# DataGridView Cellcolor

Tags: datagridview, colors

I want that the color is changed directly when the Status changes. In this Version the color changes after MessageBox.Show(). Why? Please help:)

```
                    case 0:
                        if (oldStatus == 1)
                        {
                            Dgv_Data_List.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Adresse"].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;

                        }
                        while (oldStatus == newStatus)
                        {
                            ProfDpDrv.MDPReadSlaveData(SlaveAddress, resetdiag, out dpData);
                            newStatus = dpData.m_InputData[i];
                            if(newStatus == 1)
                            {
                                Dgv_Data_List.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Adresse"].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;

                            }
                            else
                            {   
                                Dgv_Data_List.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Adresse"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;

                            }
                        }

                        MessageBox.Show("Tested");

                        break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `Dgv_Data_List.Invalidate();` after setting the color to make the program redraw.

Comment: Dgv_Data_List.Invalidate() doesnt have an effect to the DataGridView.
I fixed it with Dgv_Data_List.Refresh(). Now I have the problem that the DataGridView is flickering. I tried to fix it with DoubleBuffering but it doesnt work